# If i have a Windows Hook, which function do i need to stop packets being received?

Tags: c#, windows, hook

im able to hook registry accesses, file accesses etc- because i know which Win32 method is responsible and i can 'hook' the behaviour of this.

However, i wish to be able to 'hook'/stop packets being received when ive detected an intrusion but im not sure which Win32 function i need to 'hook'.

Does anyone know? I was getting slightly lost on the MSDN website

Answer (score 0):

The Win32 API which applications use for receiving packets is probably the "Winsock" API: see functions like `socket`, `recv`, etc.

Comment: The function i require (i think) needs to have an ASCII reference just like "RegOpenKeyExW" is used for opening registry keys, although the function is just RegOpenKeyEx

The API you mentioned doesn't seem to include the ASCII bit?

Comment: @Tom - that will be because at that point they are sending binary data - no more unicode or ascii.